Video-game themed movie from the 2000's about people travelling to Asia protecting a girl pregnant with a demon
I remember watching a movie a few years ago on HBO or something. It probably came out sometime in the 2000's. I vaguely remember what happened in it, but it went like this:
Two guys, I think one black and one white (one of them was definitely black), they might have been agents or video game testers and I think they came from America. 
They went to either Japan or China. And there was this girl who got raped by a demon in her sleep and her father/guardian had to kill her before the demon baby was born, but the agents protected her. 
There was also this video game that had things that flew out and connected to the main character's necks and in the climax of the movie where they fought the demon. Some kids were playing the video game and it controlled the main characters fighting moves in real life. Also it wasn't a horror movie.

Welcome to Movies & TV! We have a minimum standard for ID questions. Please try to add anything that may help identification.  What time period was it showing? What country was it likely from or what language was it in?Descriptions  or names of characters or actors you can give? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. You might also want to provide a more descriptive question title

Probably Samourais (2002).

Half a century ago, a Japanese family summoned a demon known as Kodeni to dispose of its adversaries. Once the killing was done, the family was cursed. Now, Tokyo Police Inspector Fujiwara is investigating the murder of a video game designer. The investigation leads him to a frightening discovery - the same lethal demon is about to be reborn. Fujiwara must travel to Paris and kill this unborn child who is the reincarnation of Kodeni and who threatens to destroy the world.

I haven't seen this movie yet, but it seems to take place in Japan, and there are a few non-asian people, white and black. Plus, there are these keywords:
woman raped by demon, impregnated by demon


Here's a review of the movie, by a French video games critic / comedian. Title of the video is "World's worst movie?" https://youtu.be/AZX9IlERs6E
